# nest if condition within a range in golang templates

Tags: go, go-templates

How to use an if condition within a range iteration loop in go?

```
package main

import "os"
import "text/template"

const t = `{{range $i, $v := .}}{{$i}} {{$v}}{{if $i gt 0}}, {{end}}
{{end}}
`

func main() {
    d := []string{"a", "b", "c"}
    template.Must(template.New("").Parse(t)).Execute(os.Stdout, d)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/IeenD90FRM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you [check the error](https://play.golang.org/p/eY5jqaYSWV) returned from `Execute`, you will find that the template is attempting to pass arguments to the non-function $i.  The correct syntax is:

```
const t = `{{range $i, $v := .}}{{$i}} {{$v}}{{if gt $i 0}}, {{end}}
{{end}}
`
```

The arguments follow the function `gt`. The function `gt` is not an [infix operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infix_notation).

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/w7tM_sQz9V)

If your goal is to print a comma separated list, then write it like this:

```
const t = `{{range $i, $v := .}}{{if $i}}, 
{{end}}{{$i}} {{$v}}{{end}}
`
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/q3lCGyTblz)

Comment: Thanks. I missed the whole prefix part when I went through the docs :)